# Break a select statement inside a while loop and create multiple tables in a while loop

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Is there a way force a statement to run a select only once inside a while loop,
For example:

```
WHILE(@NUMBERCOUNTER <@TOTALNUMBER)
BEGIN
Declare @Table2(
Id nvarchar(10)
);
Insert into @Table2
SELECT * FROM MainTable where Id in (select Id from Table1)

Insert into @Table2
SELECT * FROM MainTable where Id in (select Id from Table2)
END
```

I only want to run this line

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable where Id in (select Id from TABLE1)
```

once, then the other select to run continuous until it meets the While criteria.

Also, is there a way to separate data for each select in multiples table. I do not want the result from 2nd select get mixed with the first one.

The problem right now is that I cannot move the select statement outside the while loop, because it cannot select @Table2. And I cannot create @Table2 outside the while loop, the data will be mixed.

Note: TABLE 1 is created outside the loop

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:
You can add flag e.g.:

```
DECLARE @flag bit = 0
WHILE(@NUMBERCOUNTER <@TOTALNUMBER)
BEGIN
Declare @Table2(
Id nvarchar(10)
);
IF @flag = 0
BEGIN
Insert into @Table2
SELECT * FROM MainTable where Id in (select Id from Table1)
SET @flag = 1;
END

Insert into @Table2
SELECT * FROM MainTable where Id in (select Id from Table2)

SET @NUMBERCOUNTER = @NUMBERCOUNTER + 1; --You had infinite loop
END
```

> Also, is there a way to separate data for each select in multiples table. I do not want the result from 2nd select get mixed with the first one.

Add flag to your table @Table2 from which table row comes and include it to your select statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For my second question, adding flag to @Table inside the select statement will cause problem with subquery if the while loop goes more than 3 times. I was wondering if I can create multiple tables inside the while loop. For example:

Declare @Table[@NumberCounter]

the TableNumber corresponds to the loop number

Comment: @LegendDemonSlayer Oh, that way. So, you will need to use dynamic sql, to declare dynamically tables with proper name. There is tutorial [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).
What do you want to do with there table variables? Do you want to use them later, after while loop?
In my opinion, this will be really hard to code.

Comment: thanks. Yes I will need to return the tables back to .NET Core API(sorry if this is a bit off-sided). So if i have 4 tables, I will return results of 4 tables to .NET Core API, then this will display on html.

Comment: @LegendDemonSlayer I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with .NET Core API. There will be a problem with dynamic SQL, because you can't create table variable in one statement and use it in another or even outside of `sp_executesql` and `exec`.